# Different count results with join

Tags: sql, select, join, count, distinct

I have that `sql`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  count(KTT)
FROM 
  TRA.EVENT;
```

it returns me a number of 1901335.

Now I want to expand the sql with a `join` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  count(E.KTT)
FROM 
  TRA.EVENT E
LEFT JOIN TRA.TMP_BNAME TBN ON E.KTT = TBN.KTT_DEF;
```

But here I have a result of 1942376.

I dont understand why? I expect also a result of 1901335. I thought I easily `join` the values from `TBN` based on the entries of `EVENT`?

**EDIT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  E.KTT,
  TB.B_BEZEICHNER
FROM 
  TRA.EVENT E
LEFT JOIN TRA.TMP_BNAME TBN ON E.KTT = TBN.KTT_DEF
LEFT JOIN TRA.TMP_B TB ON TBN.B_ID = TB.B_ID;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thx for your help.
Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided full details so treat those comments as general ones.

When you join 2 tables, it may happen that it can create "duplicate" rows from one table. In your instance, there may be more than 1 record with the same `KTT_DEF` in `TRA.TMP_BNAME` table. When you join that to `TRA.EVENT` table, it create more than one record for each original record in `TRA.EVENT` table.

You may choose to count the distinct values of `KTT` from `TRA.EVENT` and use `DISTINCT` keyword but you need to put it into the `COUNT`: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E.KTT)`. This will work provided that your values are actually unique. If they are not, the count will be different from the first query.

Comment: @StefanBeike - What are you trying to do with the `LEFT JOIN` anyway? It seems pointless if you aren't doing it for the row multiplication effect.

Comment: there is a third table which I want to join. but before I have tested the current join and I was a little bit confused. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @StefanBeike Put `DISTINCT` into `COUNT`. That will work provided that your values are actually unique. If they are not, the count will be different from the first query.

Answer (score 2):

You want to count the distinct KTT?
Then your code is wrong. You have to use:

```
SELECT     count(DISTINCT KTT) 
FROM    TRA.EVENT;
```

You get different count because you count every row. Not the distinct ones. And because the join add more rows to the query thats why you get a bigger number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E.KTT)
FROM TRA.EVENT E
LEFT JOIN TRA.TMP_BNAME TBN ON E.KTT = TBN.KTT_DEF;
```